# How to run PowerShell command in R?

Tags: r, powershell

For example, this PowerShell command returns the top 5 largest files in the directory:

```
gci -r |sort Length -desc |select fullname -f 5
```

Is it possible to run it in R and assign it to a variable?

I tried this:

```
system("gci -r|sort Length -desc|select fullname -f 5")
Warning message:
running command 'gci -r|sort Length -desc|select fullname -f 5' had status 127
```

Shouldn't I use `system()` here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll probably need to run it as (assuming PowerShell is in your path):

```
system("powershell -command \"gci -r|sort Length -desc|select fullname -f 5\"")
```

or, if you're not keen on escaping `"` with `\"`.

```
system('powershell -command "gci -r|sort Length -desc|select fullname -f 5"')
```

I'm also assuming that's how R escapes and embeds quotes in strings (from my cursory googling about string handling in R).

If you wish to capture the output to a variable (specifically, a character vector) you need to use the `intern = TRUE` argument:

```
res <- system('powershell -command "gci -r|sort Length -desc|select fullname -f 5"', intern=TRUE)
```

For more information see:

> http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/system.html

In particular:

> If `intern = TRUE`, a character vector giving the output of the command, one line per character string.

and

> If `intern = FALSE`, the return value is an error code (0 for success),

Comment: That works! When I try to assign it to a `var`, I got `var
[1] 0`
`typeof(var)
[1] "integer"` How to assign the output content to a var?

Comment: @Nick - have updated my answer, but I'm at the limit of my R knowledge, I only installed it to verify my suspicions about why PowerShell wasn't launching. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the explaination.