# Open File Explorer at specified folder using R (or specifically R Studio) in Windows

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

Is there a way to open a File Explorer pane using a command in R/R Studio on Windows, with perhaps a path specified as the argument? For example:

```
open_folder(getwd())
```

would open File Explorer at the working directory. It would be like the opposite of `choose.dir`, in that you go from a path to File Explorer rather than from File Explorer to the path. It would be a command-line version of clicking on Files >> More >> Show Folder in New Window in R Studio.

I don't really know how to write code to work directly with Windows, so I'm looking for something that is already implemented or can be implemented just inside R.

Comment: See `rstudioapi::selectFile` and `...selectDirectory`. These aren't quite what you want (file dialogs not file explorer) but maybe close.

Comment: Seems related to this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082201/set-the-rstudio-files-pane-directory-from-the-r-console (difference is that one is trying to utilize the RStudio "Files" pane for the picker, rather than the OS one).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `utils::browseURL()` function is part of base R, since the `utils` package is installed as part of R. The function opens a URL, which can be of a website or a local folder.

So to open the current working directory in a File Explorer window:

```r
utils::browseURL(getwd())

# or any other folder
utils::browseURL("myfolder/myfolder2/")
```

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, it's very simple for R to run PowerShell commands (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744901/how-to-run-powershell-command-in-r)), and then for PowerShell open to File Explorer (and not simply a dialogue box) at a given directory (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320509/is-it-possible-to-open-a-windows-explorer-window-from-powershell)).

Here is a wrapper function around `base::system` to do this:

```r
od <- function(path = getwd()){
  path <- normalizePath(path)
  text_command <- paste0("powershell explorer ", path)
  system(text_command)
  invisible(TRUE)
}
```

Comment: It is very unwise to depend on PowerShell, because (1) it requires you to have PowerShell installed, (2) it becomes platform-dependent as PowerShell is not available for Linux or macOS, and (3) it is PowerShell. We're into R here, no need for other software :p

Answer (score 0):

Use

```r
rstudioapi::selectFile(path = "path/to/directory")
```

which will open a file picker.

Comment: The fn `open_folder <- function(...) invisible(rstudioapi::selectFile(...))` wraps around this to avoid printing the chosen file path (or NULL, if no file were selected).

Comment: This does not open a folder in File Explorer (Windows) or Finder (macOS) like the question was. Instead, it open a file *picker* (not even a folder picker).